# Large File Upload Results in Corrupted Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, large-files, memorystream

I am currently working on a file upload feature in my application, and I am encountering an issue where the uploaded file appears to be corrupted. The application is designed to handle large file uploads in chunks, and while it successfully collects all the chunks with matching sizes, the final assembled file seems to be corrupted and cannot be opened.

I have implemented a memory stream to handle the file chunks, and the assembled file is saved to the disk upon receiving the final chunk. Despite this, the resulting file remains inaccessible. I suspect that there might be an issue with how the memory stream is being utilized or with the final write operation to the disk.

I am using the following code to manage the file chunks and save the assembled file:

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, MemoryStream> fileChunks = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, MemoryStream>();
[HttpPost("UploadFileChunk")]
public async Task<bool> UploadFileChunk([FromBody] FileChunkDto fileChunkDto)
{
    try
    {
        // get the local filename
        string filePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\StaticFiles\\";
        string fileName = filePath + fileChunkDto.FileName;

        // delete the file if necessary
        //if (fileChunkDto.FirstChunk && System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
        //    System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);

        if (!fileChunks.TryGetValue(fileName, out MemoryStream? memoryStream))
        {
            memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            fileChunks.TryAdd(fileName, memoryStream);
        }

        memoryStream.Seek(fileChunkDto.Offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        await memoryStream.WriteAsync(fileChunkDto.Data!, 0, fileChunkDto.Data!.Length);

        if (fileChunkDto.LastChunk)
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }

            memoryStream.Dispose();

            var extention = Path.GetExtension(fileChunkDto.FileName).ToLower();
            var justFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileChunkDto.FileName);
            var (fileName2, fileType) = GetFileNameFileType(fileChunkDto.To!, justFileName);


            var to = fileChunkDto.To!.ToLower();

            var clientsRequest = new ClientsRequest()
            {
                ClientId = fileChunkDto.ClientId,
                RequestId = fileChunkDto.RequestId,
                CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow

            };

            await _context.ClientsRequests.AddAsync(clientsRequest);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            string filenameAfterConvertion = await UploadDocumentToS3(fileChunkDto, fileName, fileType);

            if (filenameAfterConvertion != null)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        return false;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var msg = ex.Message;
        return false;

    }


}
```

I suspect that there might be an issue in how I am managing the memory stream and handling the final write operation but i can't seem to figure it out

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the uploaded files are not corrupted. Thank you in advance for your assistance and also if further info needed pls do let me know in the comment.

Comment: memoryStream.Dispose() and then rused from dictionary....

Comment: Also what is the point of memory stream you can just make list off filechunks and assembly file from them... Memory wise it would be better

Comment: can you be elaborate?

Comment: the question isn't about the performance. Thanks for pointing that out. But why the file is getting corrupted? i removed the memory stream and stored the file chunks on a list of byte array. File can be opened now but the content is getting corrupted still.

Comment: Wrong data... You need to debug

Answer (score 1):

The bug is on line

```cs
memoryStream.Seek(fileChunkDto.Offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
await memoryStream.WriteAsync(fileChunkDto.Data!, 0, fileChunkDto.Data!.Length);
```

Two simultaneous requests trying to upload chunk for the same file will corrupt the memory stream as you are not putting any lock on the memory stream.

The approach is also incorrect, you are transferring all chunks and saving it in memory. You should ideally save the chunks in the file, and one file as a small independent file on server, so it would not corrupt. Each file should have a unique name based on client request. And on end, you append all files to S3 in the ascending order of chunk offset.

S3 already supports uploading in parts, you can utilize S3's own upload API to do what you are trying to do.